# SQL Trouble with Where clause

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

So I have a question about how I could go about this.

I have a table called PAPER which has a PANUM and TITLE column, another table called AUTHOR which has a PANUM and ACNUM column, and another table called ACADEMIC which has an ACNUM, GIVENNAME and FAMNAME column.

I need to grab all the PANUM's from PAPER written by the academic 'Mark' 'Yee'. Just wondering if there's a way I can grab the ACNUM of the ACADEMIC based on the GIVENNAME and FAMNAME.

So far I have this,

```
SELECT panum FROM AUTHOR, ACADEMIC
WHERE famname='Yee' AND givename='Mark'
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JOIN` You can get the `ACNUM` as Below Query:

```
SELECT AUTHOR.panum,ACADEMIC.ACNUM  FROM AUTHOR
Inner Join 
ACADEMIC ON
AUTHOR.ACNUM = ACADEMIC.ACNUM 
WHERE famname='Yee' AND givename='Mark'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Join`. 
You will successfully get the `ACNUM` from the below query:

```
SELECT ACNUM FROM ACADEMIC
WHERE famname='Yee' AND givename='Mark'
```

Now you need to modify it a little bit like this:

```
SELECT AU.PANUM,AC.ACNUM 
FROM ACADEMIC AS AC
INNER JOIN Author AS AU
ON AC.ACNUM = AU.ACNUM
WHERE famname='Yee' AND givename='Mark'
```

From above you will get all the `PANUM` associated with the given author.

How `Join` works:

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp